# grunt livereload globally for all files

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

```
livereload: {
    files: ['*.html', '*.php', 'js/**/*.{js,json}', 'css/*.css', 'img/**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'],
    options: {
        livereload: true
    }
}
```

above is my partial code of gruntfile.js, it work for my index.html which located in the same level with the gruntfile.js. What if I have many folders? How to avoid declare many example/*.php ? It's tedious every time u need to declare something just to use grunt.

Comment: Try `files: ['*/*']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
livereload: {
    files: ['**/*'],
    options: {
        livereload: true
    }
}
```